# Java code adding do while loop to make it run until user enters 0

Tags: java

Hello So this is my code and I need help with adding a do-while loop to make it run continuously until the user entered zero can anyone help?
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
Here is the code:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class calc {

```
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    

public static double sin(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.sin(a);
    return res;
}

public static double cos(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.cos(a);
    return res;
}

public static double tan(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.tan(a);
    return res;
}

public static double floor(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.floor(a);
    return res;
}

public static double ceil(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.ceil(a);
    return res;
}

public static double sqrt(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.sqrt(a);
    return res;
}

public static double cbrt(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.cbrt(a);
    return res;
}

public static double round(double val1) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.round(val1);
    return res;
}

public static double min(double a, double b) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.min(a, b);
    return res;
}

public static double max(double a, double b) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.max(a, b);
    return res;
}



public static void input() {
    
    do{
    
    System.out.println("Welcome to my scientific calculator:");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to quit");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to calculate sin value");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 to calculate cos value");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 to calculate tan value");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 to calculate floor value");
    System.out.println("Enter 5 to calculate ceil value");
    System.out.println("Enter 6 to calculate sqrt value");
    System.out.println("Enter 7 to calculate cbrt value");
    System.out.println("Enter 8 to calculate round value");
    System.out.println("Enter 9 to calculate min value");
    System.out.println("Enter 10 to calculate max value");
    System.out.println("Enter 11 to multiply");
    System.out.println("Enter 12 to divide");
    System.out.println("Enter 13 to subtract");
    System.out.println("Enter 14 to add");
    
    int input = in.nextInt();

    double val1 = 0.0, val2 = 0.0;
    
    switch (input) {
     case 0:
        System.out.println("You quit!");
        break;

    case 1:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Sin-" + val1 + "=" + sin(val1));
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Cos2-" + val1 + "=" + cos(val1));
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Tan-" + val1 + "=" + tan(val1));
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Floor-" + val1 + "=" + floor(val1));
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ceil-" + val1 + "=" + ceil(val1));
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Sqrt-" + val1 + "=" + sqrt(val1));
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Cbrt-" + val1 + "=" + cbrt(val1));
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("round-" + val1 + "=" + round(val1));
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("The smallest number of the two numbers is " + Math.min(val1,val2));
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The larger number of the two numbers is " + Math.max(val1,val2));
        break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        double total =val1*val2;
        System.out.println("The total is " + total);
        break;
    case 12:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        double total2 =val1/val2;
        System.out.println("The total is " + total2);
        break;
    case 13:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        double total1 =val1-val2;
        System.out.println("The total is " + total1);
        break;
    case 14:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        double total3 =val1+val2;
        System.out.println("The total is " + total3);
        break;

        
    default:
        System.out.println("Thank You for using my calculator!");   
    
        }while(input!=0);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    input();
}
```

}

Comment: where is the case 0: in the code?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.  There is no loop

Comment: No.  Read up about `do while` loops and give it a try.  Then edit this post with whatever you end up adding.

Comment: The algorithm this site uses encourages you to explain your code in text. Please do not put nonsense characters into your question.

Answer (score 1):

If by zero you meant '0' you could simply add a switch case that prints a message and exits something like.

```java
    case 0:
        System.out.println("Thank You for using my calculator!");
        System.exit()
        break;
```

If no input then you can use in.hasNextInt() to terminate

Comment: Thx but how do I get the rest of it to repeat? even after lets say the user enters 14 and the program adds it and gives the total how do I get that to repeat?

Comment: in this way you need to add while (true) {...} around the code you want to repeat

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calc {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



    public static double sin(double a) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.sin(a);
        return res;
    }

    public static double cos(double a) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.cos(a);
        return res;
    }

    public static double tan(double a) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.tan(a);
        return res;
    }

    public static double floor(double a) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.floor(a);
        return res;
    }

    public static double ceil(double a) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.ceil(a);
        return res;
    }

    public static double sqrt(double a) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.sqrt(a);
        return res;
    }

    public static double cbrt(double a) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.cbrt(a);
        return res;
    }

    public static double round(double val1) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.round(val1);
        return res;
    }

    public static double min(double a, double b) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.min(a, b);
        return res;
    }

    public static double max(double a, double b) {
        double res = 0.0;
        res = Math.max(a, b);
        return res;
    }



    public static void input() {



        System.out.println("Welcome to my scientific calculator:");

        int input;//added this
        do {//added this
            System.out.println("Enter 0 to quit");
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to calculate sin value");
            System.out.println("Enter 2 to calculate cos value");
            System.out.println("Enter 3 to calculate tan value");
            System.out.println("Enter 4 to calculate floor value");
            System.out.println("Enter 5 to calculate ceil value");
            System.out.println("Enter 6 to calculate sqrt value");
            System.out.println("Enter 7 to calculate cbrt value");
            System.out.println("Enter 8 to calculate round value");
            System.out.println("Enter 9 to calculate min value");
            System.out.println("Enter 10 to calculate max value");
            System.out.println("Enter 11 to multiply");
            System.out.println("Enter 12 to divide");
            System.out.println("Enter 13 to subtract");
            System.out.println("Enter 14 to add");


            input = in.nextInt();//changed this

            double val1 = 0.0, val2 = 0.0;

            switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Sin-" + val1 + "=" + sin(val1));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Cos2-" + val1 + "=" + cos(val1));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Tan-" + val1 + "=" + tan(val1));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Floor-" + val1 + "=" + floor(val1));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Ceil-" + val1 + "=" + ceil(val1));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Sqrt-" + val1 + "=" + sqrt(val1));
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Cbrt-" + val1 + "=" + cbrt(val1));
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("round-" + val1 + "=" + round(val1));
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val2 = in.nextDouble();

                    System.out.println("The smallest number of the two numbers is " + Math.min(val1, val2));
                    break;
                case 10:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val2 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("The larger number of the two numbers is " + Math.max(val1, val2));
                    break;
                case 11:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val2 = in.nextDouble();
                    double total = val1 * val2;
                    System.out.println("The total is " + total);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val2 = in.nextDouble();
                    double total2 = val1 / val2;
                    System.out.println("The total is " + total2);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val2 = in.nextDouble();
                    double total1 = val1 - val2;
                    System.out.println("The total is " + total1);
                    break;
                case 14:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val1 = in.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
                    val2 = in.nextDouble();
                    double total3 = val1 + val2;
                    System.out.println("The total is " + total3);
                    break;


                default:
                    System.out.println("Thank You for using my calculator!");


            }
        } while (input != 0);//added this
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program has lots of bugs.
I have corrected it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calc {

public static double sin(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.sin(a);
    return res;
}

public static double cos(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.cos(a);
    return res;
}

public static double tan(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.tan(a);
    return res;
}

public static double floor(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.floor(a);
    return res;
}

public static double ceil(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.ceil(a);
    return res;
}

public static double sqrt(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.sqrt(a);
    return res;
}

public static double cbrt(double a) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.cbrt(a);
    return res;
}

public static double round(double val1) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.round(val1);
    return res;
}

public static double min(double a, double b) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.min(a, b);
    return res;
}

public static double max(double a, double b) {
    double res = 0.0;
    res = Math.max(a, b);
    return res;
}



public  static  void input() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    do{
    
    System.out.println("Welcome to my scientific calculator:");
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to quit");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to calculate sin value");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 to calculate cos value");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 to calculate tan value");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 to calculate floor value");
    System.out.println("Enter 5 to calculate ceil value");
    System.out.println("Enter 6 to calculate sqrt value");
    System.out.println("Enter 7 to calculate cbrt value");
    System.out.println("Enter 8 to calculate round value");
    System.out.println("Enter 9 to calculate min value");
    System.out.println("Enter 10 to calculate max value");
    System.out.println("Enter 11 to multiply");
    System.out.println("Enter 12 to divide");
    System.out.println("Enter 13 to subtract");
    System.out.println("Enter 14 to add");
    
    int option = in.nextInt();

    double val1 = 0.0, val2 = 0.0;

    if (option==0){
       System.out.println("You quit!"); 
       break;
    }
    
    switch (option) {
     
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Sin-" + val1 + "=" + sin(val1));
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Cos2-" + val1 + "=" + cos(val1));
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Tan-" + val1 + "=" + tan(val1));
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Floor-" + val1 + "=" + floor(val1));
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ceil-" + val1 + "=" + ceil(val1));
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Sqrt-" + val1 + "=" + sqrt(val1));
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Cbrt-" + val1 + "=" + cbrt(val1));
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("round-" + val1 + "=" + round(val1));
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("The smallest number of the two numbers is " + Math.min(val1,val2));
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The larger number of the two numbers is " + Math.max(val1,val2));
        break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        double total =val1*val2;
        System.out.println("The total is " + total);
        break;
    case 12:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        double total2 =val1/val2;
        System.out.println("The total is " + total2);
        break;
    case 13:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        double total1 =val1-val2;
        System.out.println("The total is " + total1);
        break;
    case 14:
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the value :");
        val2 = in.nextDouble();
        double total3 =val1+val2;
        System.out.println("The total is " + total3);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Thank You for using my calculator!");   
    }
    }while(true);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input();
    }
}
```

Run this and find the difference and realise your mistakes.